# No sound in flash

Tags: audio, flash

I'm experiencing problems with sound in Flash Videos. 
It started under Chrome browser and is now in Firefox as well.

Chrome: Version 23.0.1271.97 m 
Flash version (under firefox->addons->plugins):  11.5.502.135 
Firefox: 17.0.1 
Windows: 7 Home Premium SP 1

I tried installing codecs (k-lite), deleting Appdata (both Macromedia & Adobe) folders, Emptying the Temporary Internet Files.. 
 
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Sound output works everywhere else?

Comment: yeah, VLC/Spotify/Winamp all works perfectly.

Comment: Volume in systray → Mixer: Check all volumes are not X out. Are they?